# Write definition files for modules exports a function returning a module

Tags: node.js, typescript, tsd

I am recently writing definition files for node.js module "mongoose-bird". This module exports a function returning a module. With guides on the internet, I wrote this:

```
declare module "mongoose-bird" {
  export = () => MongooseAsync;
  module MongooseAsync {
...
```

But I found that with the following code, the type system cannot work properly:

```
import mongoose_bird = require('mongoose-bird');
var mongoose = mongoose_bird();
...
export interface IUser extends mongoose.Document {
```

Since `tsc` reports error `TS2503`

```
error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'mongoose'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'mongoose'.

Because you made your file a module (disconnected from the global namespace) by using `import`.

Recommend a `.d.ts` for (a hand wavy) declaration only with a corresponding `.ts` for implementation.